# Getting the number of rows returned by a bcp query?

Tags: c#, bcp

Please help!!! I'm executing the bcp query using C# application. Currently for finding no of rows returned by the bcp query I'm using a file reader to get the count from the file created as a result of bcp query, Is there a way to get the count as result of execution in c#?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could look at the logs to identify this information. Or create a log file and output such information. The following links could help.

Good Luck!
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx